# Xamarin.Android fast deployment is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Fast Deployment property is disabled in my Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio for Mac.
How can I enable this property for fast debugging?
I tried create a test project and this option is able to check, but not in my current project.
Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you need to change your project Release mode to debug mode. To enable fast deployment.

Comment: Usually(?) that is disabled for only for Release builds, try placing `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>` within the Debug  configuration `PropertyGroup`

Comment: But it debug mode

Comment: @SushiHangover it's debug

Comment: @Atlantis What happened you you added EmbedAssembliesIntoApk ?

Comment: @SushiHangover nothing. CheckBox is disabled

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @DominikR you know. After the last update of VC for Mac this checkbox is active now.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, the *Fast Assembly Deployment* property was grayed out even for debug targets.

What helped in my case was to go to the csproj file and manually change the content of the `<DebugType>` property from *Full* (capital F) to *full* (small f):

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```

Afterwards, the *Fast Assembly Deployment* property was not grayed out anymore.

The `<DebugType>` property in the csproj file corresponds to the *Debug information* property in the Android Compiler settings dialog. It seems when selecting *Full* in the settings dialog, its value is stored as *Full* in the csproj file, but the depending property *Fast Assembly Deployment* seems to expect the value *full* to get enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue changing the Debug PropertyGroup on the csproj as follows:

```
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so old but still not fixed.
My solution was to add it to the project file manually:

1. unload the project, double-click it to edit,
2. find the PropertyGroup containing the Condition for your build configuration
3. add this line:`<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>`

Answer (score -2):

change your project from Debug mode to Release mode and it will be enable